# Phonegap/Cordova in-app payment

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

We are building an `Phonegap/Cordova` app, where the members will start paying a subscription fee after 6 months of using it.

So if the user downloads the app and registers/logins, then they will use the app for free and then pay after 6 months, which will allow them to use it for further 1 year.

Similar to Whatsapp payment.

Is it possible or are there any plugins to get this done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate [Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin) Payment gateway for cordova/phonegap application.
Refer to [documentation](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/) for the underlying PayPal Mobile SDK.

Comment: We have got normal payment for buying credits on the app, but locking the app after 6 months for subscription payment similar to whatsapp?

Comment: This is a violation of Apple and Google's TOS agreements. Any payments for a free app must go through the respective app store payment processor.